# jsPDF how to create a multiline editable acrobat reader form field with dynamic height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, acrobat, html-to-pdf

I've got the editable part down and it seems to be multi line but as you type into the field the height of the field stays the same and the font just gets smaller.
[image]

```
    doc.text(20, 220, "Notes:");
    var notesField = new TextField();
    notesField.multiline = true;
    notesField.maxFontSize = 12;
    notesField.height = 150;
    notesField.Rect = [280, 202, 160, 18];
    notesField.fontSize = 12;
    doc.addField(notesField);
```

Comment: That's how multiline fields work in Acrobat. The text adjusts to the size of the field. You can't have a field with a dynamic height as an AcroForm field. You'd need to create an XFA form, which jsPDF doesn't currently support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for creating a multiline box with a fixed height.
I haven't figured out how to create one with a dynamic height yet.

````
 doc.text(20, 220, "Notes:");
 var notesField = new TextField();
 notesField.multiline = true;
 notesField.maxFontSize = 12;
 notesField.height = 150;
 notesField.Rect = [280, 202, 160, 148];
 notesField.fontSize = 12;
 doc.addField(notesField);
 doc.line(280, 200, 440, 200);```
````

Comment: You can't. See my comment in the original post.

Comment: Thanks Joel, write a answer so i can give you solved points

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can't have a field with a dynamic height as an AcroForm field. You'd need to create an XFA form, which jsPDF doesn't currently support.